# how to pay for teams graph api

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using teams graph api, this api need to pay, and I also met the exception, which told me to pay for it, but I can't find how to pay it from the given link, the link is as below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-licenses

In additional, I also want to know if I continue to use the Evaluation Mode after paid, it seems there is no price for Evaluation Mode, so I have to use Model A or Model B?

Best Regards

Comment: In general, you need to purchase a subscription and create app registrations with API permissions.
Still we will check it internally and let you know, if we find any.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft, thanks for your comment, I have purchased the subscription, and created the Azure APP, but I didn't find where I can bring them together; Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please follow this document for billing/payment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/create-subscription
2. Evaluation model should only be used for testing the API. You cannot use evaluation mode once you reach the evaluation quota for that month. You will need to choose from either Model A or Model B. Model A is license based model and Model B is consumption based model. The requirements for the different models are specified in this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-licenses

Comment: @Brooke.Li - Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?